# Data Annotations not working with chosen jquery plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, jquery-chosen, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a form which has multiple htmlhelper controls like textboxes and dropdownlists. I have used data annotation to do validation on the various fields and used qtip to show the validation messages.Also I have used the chosen jquery plugin for enhancing the UI. If chosen plugin called then data annotation is not working.Validation working for itemlist but not for other two.. Kindly help with any inputs. Here is my code:

My View
IndentItem.cshtml

```
if (ViewBag.isCreate == true)
 {
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IndentId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ItemCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ItemType)

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentMachineId, Model.DepartmentMachineList, new { @class = "machineList input-medium" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.DepartmentMachineId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemName, Model.ItemNameList, new { @class = "itemList input-medium" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryName, Model.CategoryNameList, new { @class = "catList input-medium" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListCustomFor(model => model.ItemId, Model.ItemCodeList, new { @class = "codeList input-medium" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ItemUnitDescription, new { placeholder = "unit type", @class = "input-small", @readonly = "true" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestedQuantity, new { placeholder = "quantity", @class = "input-small" })
    </td>

<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" >Save changes</button>`</div>
```

My Model

```
public class IndentItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Autogenerated Purchase Indent ID
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("S.No")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Editable(false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "S.No Required")]
    [Key()]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Editable(false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indent Id Required")]
    public string IndentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// machine number
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Machine number")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Machine number Required")]
    public string DepartmentMachineId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentMachineList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Item name
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Item name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item name Required")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Item ID")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item ID Required")]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type of units
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("???")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Editable(true)]
    public string ItemType { get; set; }

    public string ItemUnitDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Category
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Required")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of possible categories
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Category")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryNameList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Item code
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Item code")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Editable(true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item code Required")]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of possible Item codes
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Item code")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItemEx> ItemCodeList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// number of items
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Required quantity")]
    [Range(typeof(int), "1", "100000")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive whole number.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public int RequestedQuantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// number of items
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Issued")]
    [Range(typeof(int), "0", "100000")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive whole number.")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public int IssuedQuantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// number of items
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Balance")]
    [Range(typeof(int), "0", "100000")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive whole number.")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public int BalanceQuantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// number of items returned
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Return")]
    [Range(typeof(int), "0", "100000")]
    [DataAnnotationsExtensions.Integer(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive whole number.")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public int ReturnQuantity { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItemEx> ItemList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemNameList { get; set; }   


    }
}
```

> ```
>   $(".itemList").change(GetItemCategories);
>     $(".catList").chosen().change(GetItems);
>     $(".codeList").chosen().change(SetItem);
> ```

Comment: What validation errors are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting required error for dropdownlist..

Comment: But its a `<select>` so something will always be selected (unless you have used javascript to set the elements `selectedIndex` property to `-1`)

Comment: Or you can use the overload which adds an empty option `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.ItemName, Model.ItemNameList, "--please select name--", new { @class = "itemList input-medium" })`

Comment: yes i have a javascript which sets the first option as text select an option..I tried doing what you have mentioned as well..but still i have the same issue.

Comment: What does the javascript do? Are you also setting `$('#yourselect').val('');`?

Comment: im setting the placeholder text in js.. no have not set $('#yourselect').val('');

Comment: But that's not changing the **value** of the select (which is what posts back).

Comment: I am sorry but i did not understand what u r trying to say

Comment: Just use the overload I mentioned above and delete the javascript.

Comment: Well I just tried it in my app and its working fine so I suggest there is something else wrong

Comment: There is a small update in this issue.I found that the issue is caused because I am using a chosen jquery plugin for better UI.This chosen is interfering with the data annotation validation.  $(".itemList").change(GetItemCategories);
$(".catList").chosen().change(GetItems); Here validation fires for dropdown itemlist but it is not fired for catlist since I have called chosen().Is there any way around this?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the Chosen plugin.